# В чем причина того, что localStorage не совсем правильно отрабатывает после перезагрузки страницы ? VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, localstorage, vue-router

Ребята, кто может помочь понять, в чем причина того, что localStorage не совсем правильно отрабатывает после перезагрузки страницы ?

Получается, если я добавляю такой же товар, как я добавил перед этим - отлично срабатывает и в localStorage.cats - этот объект не добавляется(т.к. он уже существует)

localStorage.cats после перезагрузки существует и товар(объект) уже находится в нём

Но если перезагружу страницу - то он снова добавляется.

```
data() {
            return {
                cats : [] , // массив, собирает объекты товаров
            }
        },
methods: {
     addToCart(product){               
                /*sweet Alert кусок кода*/
                .then((result) => {
                        /*Проверка на заданный товар в корзине*/
                        if (this.cats.includes(product)){
                            result.isConfirmed = false;
                        }
                        

                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        //Send request to the server
                        this.form.post('products/add/'+product.id).then(()=>{
                            this.cats.push(product);
                            this.saveLocalProducts();
                            console.log(result.isConfirmed);
                            console.log(this.sessionCookie);
                            console.log(localStorage.sessionCookie);
                            Swal.fire(
                                'Успешно!',
                                'Продукт '+this.productToCart.title+' был добавлен',
                                'success'
                            );
                        }).catch(() => {
                            Swal.fire({
                                title: 'Error!',
                                text: 'Somthing went wrong',
                                icon: 'error',
                                confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
                            })
                        });
                    } //result finish
                })
            },

            saveLocalProducts(){
                const parsed = JSON.stringify(this.cats);
                localStorage.setItem('cats', parsed);
            },
mounted() {

        if (localStorage.getItem('cats')) {
            try {
                this.cats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cats'));
                console.log(this.cats);
            } catch(e) {
                localStorage.removeItem('cats');
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: в приведенном коде нет места, в котором бы читалось значение из localStorage. Видна только запись

Comment: @Grundy сейчас исправлю, забыл добавить код из mounted()

Comment: @Grundy - решил проблему методом find() - хотя почему этот метод (includes) не работает как нужно - немного непонятно... вроде тоже ищет по массиву...

Comment: includes - проверяет наличие того же самого объекта, если ты каждый раз проверяешь новый объект - естественно он вернет false

Comment: @Grundy Вы имеете ввиду, что когда страница перезагружается, он проверяет уже новый массив со значениями ?

Comment: что-то вроде этого